# Python subarray from dataclass array

Tags: python, arrays, python-dataclasses

i Have th following dataclass

```py
@dataclass
class Cell:
   electric_field: np.double=0
   boarder_left: np.double=0
   boarder_right: np.double=0
```

i do an array of it like this. by the way is this the best way?

```py
Cell_Array = []
for i in range(cnt):
  cell=Cell()
  Cell_Array.append(cell)
```

now i would like to have an array from the electric field of all cells. what would be the best way ?

Comment: please fix the syntax of the snippets in your question, The last one is featuring random indentation: that is not just aesthetical in Python.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an array of `electric_field` attributes from all the instances you can do this:

```
all_electric_fields = []
for cell in Cell_Array:
    all_electric_fields.append(cell.electric_fields)
```

Comment: thank you for your comment!
I am currently doing exactly this. 
I am afraid its slow. and I was wondering if there is an shorter nicer to read statement

something more like:
```python
Cell_Array.all_electric_fields
```